# why .net RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString throw bad data error

Tags: java, .net, rsa

I have a RSA private key which generated by Java in server side, my client side is a .net application, So I need to covert the private key into .net accepted format.

Here is my code in server side written by java:

```java
 public String getRSAPrivateKeyAsNetFormat(byte[] encodedPrivkey) {
        try {
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(2048);    
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pvkKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivkey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");                              
            RSAPrivateCrtKey pvkKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(pvkKeySpec);
            buff.append("<RSAKeyValue>");   
            buff.append("<Modulus>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getModulus().toByteArray())) + "</Modulus>");       
            buff.append("<Exponent>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray())) + "</Exponent>");      
            buff.append("<P>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getPrimeP().toByteArray())) + "</P>");   
            buff.append("<Q>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getPrimeQ().toByteArray())) + "</Q>");    
            buff.append("<DP>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getPrimeExponentP().toByteArray())) + "</DP>");
            buff.append("<DQ>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getPrimeExponentQ().toByteArray())) + "</DQ>");
buff.append("<InverseQ>" + b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getCrtCoefficient().toByteArray())) + "</InverseQ>");    
            buff.append("<D>"+ b64encode(removeMSZero(pvkKey.getPrivateExponent().toByteArray())) + "</D>");
            buff.append("</RSAKeyValue>");    
            return buff.toString().replaceAll("[ \t\n\r]", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("324234234");
            System.err.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the code to use private key in client side is like this, which written by .net

```cs
    using (var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
       rsaProvider.FromXmlString(key);
    }
```

this code works for most of users, but FromXmlString method throw a "bad data" exception for one user. I don't know why it happends, Any information will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you sharing private keys between entities?

Comment: This is legacy code, we have not time to change it.